# Data Repeater, make linklabel open link in browser?

Tags: url, datarepeater, linklabel

I have a datarepeater set up, i have a linklabel showing a link to a webpage. How do i go about making this open in a browser?

I know i should be using

`Shell("c:/program files/internet explorer/iexplore.exe URLHERE")`

Or similar.

But i dont see how to make it call the value and then create it as a link for that linklabel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your linklabel text set as the URL, if so use this in the linklabel click handler

```
Shell("c:/program files/internet explorer/iexplore.exe" & sender.text)
```